# Pandas функция обратная Group By

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Помогите пожалуйста, есть датафрейм:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Code":["001","002","003","001"],"Products":["Name1","Name2","Name3","Name1"],
                   "Qty":["1","2","1","1"],"Person":["Mr_X","Mr_X","Mr_Y","Ms_X"]})

  Code Products Qty Person
0  001    Name1   1   Mr_X
1  002    Name2   2   Mr_X
2  003    Name3   1   Mr_Y
3  001    Name1   1   Ms_X
```

нужно дописать такое же количество строк, где QTY > 1, т.е по факту нужна функция обратная Group By. Что хотелось бы получить:

```
  Code Products Qty Person
0  001    Name1   1   Mr_X
1  002    Name2   1   Mr_X
2  002    Name2   1   Mr_X
3  003    Name3   1   Mr_Y
4  001    Name1   1   Ms_X
```

понимаю, что очень коряво, но пытался решить проблему таким способом:

```
for ind , row in df.iterrows():
    if row["Qty"] > 1:
        x = row["Qty"]
        row["Qty"] = 1
        for i in range (x-1):
            df = pd.concat((df, row.iloc[:,:]))
```

возвращается ошибка:  Too many indexers
Вопрос - Есть ли функция обратная Group By, если нет, то как исправить код?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так:

Воспользуйтесь *repeat* и затем замените все значения на 1

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.repeat(df.Qty, axis=0), columns=df.columns)
new_df['Qty'] = 1

>>> new_df
    Code    Products    Qty Person
0    001    Name1         1 Mr_X
1    002    Name2         1 Mr_X
2    002    Name2         1 Mr_X
3    003    Name3         1 Mr_Y
4    001    Name1         1 Ms_X
```